# TCP: RST after ACK when limiter is in place

Tags: tcp

We are seeing TCP connections sporadically fail to establish, when a bandwidth limiter is placed on the network regardless of whether the limit is being hit.

Below are links to some packet captures which demonstrate this, when connecting to an arbitrary TCP service. One capture shows a working connection and the other a failed connection. There are also two of a failed connection, taken from client and server side.

The service seems irrelevant here - we've tried connecting to different TCP services on the server.

The captures show the server sending a RST to the client, after it has received the ACK.

What is causing the server to send the RST, in the failed example?

PCAP links are:

- Working: http://phil.lavin.me.uk/downloads/pcaps/working.pcap
- Failed: http://phil.lavin.me.uk/downloads/pcaps/failed.pcap

By request, here is a pcap taken on both client and server during a single failed connection:

- Client: http://phil.lavin.me.uk/downloads/pcaps/client.pcap
- Server: http://phil.lavin.me.uk/downloads/pcaps/server.pcap

Comment: what is the bandwidth limiter?

Comment: Where were the captures taken, on the client (or between client and limiter) or on the server (or between limiter and server)? Could you get simultaneous client and server side captures of a failing connection? The reason I'm asking is because it *might* be the limiter sending the RST ?

Comment: Captures were taken on the server. I've taken captures on the client and the limiter - they all look the same. It is most certainly the server that is sending the RST.

Comment: The limiter here is pfSense

Comment: I was breaking my head over this as I really couldn't see anything wrong with the ACK, so I'm glad you found the cause so fast :) Now, you can't see whether SYN cookies are used, the 'cookie' is really the initial SEQ  value in the SYN+ACK. If you want to dig deeper into this would you mind posting a client and server capture of the same failed connection please? Also: was the "working" pcap taken without the limiter in place? Edit: it seems you removed your comment about the SYN cookies while I was writing my comment?

Comment: Yes, sorry. Turning off SYN Cookies appeared to fix the problem but it hasn't done so. The "working" pcap was taken with the limiter in place. Not all connections fail when it is in place - only a handful (perhaps 25%).

Comment: Ok so back to square 1. Can we get simultaneous captures on client and server please. If those are identical (bit by bit) then something's wrong on the server and the presence of the limiter is coincidence. On the other hand if the limiter is modifying the SYN or the ACK then seeing what exactly it changes, will hopefully give us a clue as to why the server doesn't like the ACK.

Comment: I edited the post to add the 2 request pcaps

Comment: Still breaking my head over this... the only modification I could spot is the MSS in the SYN, but I don't see how that could cause the server to reject the ACK. BTW are you seeing this problem with normal 'real life' network traffic or are you generating some kind of test traffic to test the limiter? And either way, are you also seeing the same problem when the limiter is not in place? I assumed you did not, but I should have asked.

Comment: We are seeing problems with real traffic. Connections are failing to establish. When the limiter is turned off, the problem does not exist. The problem exists, when the limiter is in place, even when it is not being maxed out (i.e. no packets are being dropped).